# laravel 5.6 Cómo mostrar decimales .00 automaticamente al entrar un entero en formulario

Tags: laravel

estoy utilizando Laravel 5.6 Mi pregunta es la siguiente: En un formulario normal de laravel quiero que me muestre los valores por ejemplo con tres decimales. la cosa es que si escribo 3 automáticamente me muestre 3.000, tambien cuando edito si en la base datos ya tengo registrado por ejemplo 1.000 en el formulario solo me muestra 1 y deseo que se muestra tal y como está 1.000. Gracias de antemano. no se si se podria lograr con javascript. Un ejemplo del formulario podria ser este:

```
<div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('import','Importe')!!}
      {!! Form::text('import',null, ['class'=>'form-control-sm']) !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El punto se usa como separados decimal en formato americano y la coma como separador de millares, es decir al contrario que nosotros.
Entonces tu número 1000 que expresas como 1.000 para los anglosajones sería 1,000 pero el número 1 coma 000, es decir 1,000 ellos lo entiende como nosotros: 1.000.

En PHP se usa la función [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) para usar uno y otro formato y establecer el número de decimales de un número.

`number_format()` acepta varios parámetros, el primero el número. Un ejemplo:

```
<?php
$num = 1999.99;
echo(number_format($num)); // 2,000
```

Redondea el número ya que no le estamos indicando decimales y devuelve *dos mil* no 2 coma 000.

El segundo parámetro de la función es el número de decimales, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$num = 1999.99;
echo(number_format($num, 2)); // 1,999.99
```

ahora no ha redondeado el número, ya que no era necesario eliminar los decimales de entrada.

Fíjate que la función, por defecto, devuelve los números en formato americano. Los parámetros 3 y 4 nos permiten indicar separadores de decimales y de unidades de millar, en este orden. Debes indicar ambos para obtener tus números en "español". Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$num = 1999.99;
echo(number_format($num, 2, ',', '.')); // 1.999,99
```

En cuanto al formato en que se muestran los números en un *input de tipo texto*, tu decides, para controlar como se muestran las entradas, tendrías que usar Javascript. Aquí tienes un hilo relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178332/force-decimal-point-instead-of-comma-in-html5-number-input-client-side